# Idris `foldl` default implementation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fold, idris, dependent-type

```hs
interface Foldable t where
  foldr : (func : elem -> acc -> acc) -> (init : acc) -> (input : t elem) -> acc
  foldl : (func : acc -> elem -> acc) -> (init : acc) -> (input : t elem) -> acc
  foldl f z t = foldr (flip (.) . flip f) id t z
```

What does `foldr (flip (.) . flip f) id t z` mean here?
And is there another way to implement `foldl` using `foldr`?
Thanks for answering.

Comment: What part of the definition is unclear? Do you know what `flip` and `(.)` do?

Comment: @chepner Yes, but what `id` is doing and their combination seems unclear to me...

Comment: `id` is the identity function. It's the also the identity element for function composition: `f . id == f` and `id . f == f`.

Comment: Ah, I got it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument in the `foldl` defined above could be turned into a lambda like this:

```
\element -> (. (flip f element))
-- or
\element prevFun -> prevFun . flip f element
-- or
\element prevFun next -> prevFun $ f next element
```

Let's take an example where you want to fold left over a list `[a, b, c]`. You want your end result to be `f (f (f z a) b) c)`, where `z` is the accumulator.

In the first iteration, the first argument would be `c` and the second `id`. Thus, the result would be `id . flip f c`, or just `flip f c` (since `id . f` is simply `f`, as @chepner pointed out).

The second iteration would result in `flip f c . flip f b`, and after that you would get `flip f c . flip f b . flip f a` (basically, adding a `. flip f x` for every next element `x`.

This expands to:

```
acc -> flip f c (flip f b (flip f a acc))
-- or
acc -> flip f c (flip f b (f acc a))
-- or
acc -> f (f (f acc a) b) c)
```

Et voila! We have a function that takes an accumulator `acc`, and returns the result of `foldl f acc t`, so we simply apply that to `z`, the actual accumulator.

Comment: Thanks! After rewriting it to avoid point free style, I found it easier to understand.